# Deleted azure search as part of Web App bot

Tags: botframework, azure-bot-service, azure-qna-maker

I had published my QnAMaker bot to Azure using the Publish option on the QnAMaker portal. Since I couldn't update the pricing tier in the Azure search service (that was created along with my WebApp bot), I deleted the existing one and created a new one. Now I don't see any KBs in my QnA Maker portal. I cant edit/ republish the KBs. Is there any way to retrieve my KB/ azure search indexes?

Comment: In my experience, no. There doesn't seem to be a method to back up or restore a QnAMaker bot. If the KBs are gone, they're gone forever.

Comment: Do you just delete the search service? I *thought* it was possible to migrate to a new search service but maybe I'm wrong since it does hold the knowledge base indexes.